# wp_query on page template not working (Genesis framework)

Tags: wp-query, page-template, genesis-theme-framework

I'm trying to use wp_query as part of a page template. The page is tagged with a taxonomy term and I'm trying to grab a list of posts that are also tagged with this taxonomy term.

I'm able to grab the term itself from the page no problem, and use them as part of the $args which seem to be working ok as well.

However anything that uses WP_Query even with global $post returns nothing, and any code below the wp_query in the function won't execute.

I'm utilising the Genesis framework so this may have something to do with it but I'm really struggling to figure this out. using WP_Query in shortcodes has functioned fine so why not here?

Here is the code

```
/**
 * Template Name: Car Page
 *
 */

add_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'racelistfunc2' );

function racelistfunc2() {
   $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'vehicle' ) ;
   if ($terms) {
    $terms_slugs = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $terms_slugs[] = $term->slug;
    }
    $race = $terms_slugs[0];      
   }



    $args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
        'taxonomy' => 'vehicle',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $race

    )
)
    );

 echo $race; /* test to see if all functioning ok (it is here) */


       $race_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

   if ($race_posts->have_posts()) {
       while ( $race_posts->have_posts() ) {
           $race_posts->the_post();
    $html .= "<li class='racelistnum'><a href='" . get_permalink($post->ID) . "'>" . get_the_title() . "</a></li>";
    return $html;
      }
   }
      else  {   
      $html .= "<p>no posts lol </p>";
    return $html; 

      }
       wp_reset_postdata();

    echo 'test here'; /* no code functions here */

     }

    genesis();
```

Comment: if this is your actual code, you can see the problem above, the comment after `echo $race;` isn't closed.

Comment: oops! no that was just inserted for the basis of this question!

Comment: `return $html;` inside your while loop is halting execution and exiting the function.

Comment: shouldn't it be `echo $html;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues are seen here -

1. You have hooked a function in a template file whereas such code should go in `functions.php` instead or you can directly put the code of this function in the template.
2. You does not seem to be getting value of `$post` inside this function.
3. Both the `return` statements should be removed and just `echo $html;` should be placed just after the `wp_reset_postdata()` in your current code.

Comment: Argh it really was just because of echo! The simplest explanation is usually the right one! Also it has to be a function due to the way Genesis works :\ Working fine now, thanks!